# make function take multiple variables from an array passed in as parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

How to make function take multiple variables from an array passed in as parameter?

> Edited

For example:

Achieve this:

```
const inputObj = [
 ['Anna', 10, 'Monday'],
 ['Anna', 15, 'Wednesday'],
 ['Beatrice', 8, 'Monday'],
 ['Beatrice', 11, 'Wednesday'],
 ['Anna', 4, 'Wednesday'],
 ['Beatrice', 5, 'Monday'],
 ['Beatrice', 16, 'Monday']
]
// expected output:
const outputObj = [ 
[ 'Anna', 10, 'Monday' ],
  [ 'Anna', 19, 'Wednesday' ],
  [ 'Beatrice', 29, 'Monday' ],
  [ 'Beatrice', 11, 'Wednesday' ] 
]

const arr = [0, 2]

const someFunction = (obj, v, a) => {
    const result = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const key = `${cur[a[0]]}|${cur[a[1]]}`
        if(!acc[key]) acc[key] = cur
        else acc[key][1] += cur[v]
        return acc
      }, {})
    return Object.values(result)
}


console.log(someFunction(inputObj, 1, arr))
```

with this:

```
const arr = [0, 2, 3, ...] // basically the array could contain any number of items.

const someFunction = (obj, v, objParams) => {
      const result = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      const key = ??? 
      ...
      }, {})
}
```

So that the function can be reused and it accepts custom-sized arrays, check if the column numbers in the array are the same, then adds the sum of the column that is passed in as `v`?

How to declare the variables from the objParams to achieve the same result as the code above does?

Also how to add `v` in the middle of `cur`?

Comment: `const key = objParams.join('|')` seems to be what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming objParams is an array of unknown size (strings in this example):

```
const objParams = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];
const key = objParams.join(']}|${cur[');
const built = '${cur[' + key + ']';
```

Built is:

```
${cur[c1]}|${cur[c2]}|${cur[c3]
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. It returns the right key but the key doesn't work. Try console.log(key), it returns the key itself as a string, not the values of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you can use the spread operator in the argument definition.

More reading about spread operator on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function sum(...args) {
  return args.reduce((result, value) => result + value, 0)
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

console.log('sum', sum(2, 2));
console.log('sum', sum(...numbers));
console.log('sum', sum(1, 2, 1, ...numbers));

// get single args before accumulating the rest
function sum2(foo, bar, ...args) {
  return args.reduce((result, value) => result + value, 0)
}

console.log('sum2', sum2(2, 2));
console.log('sum2', sum2(...numbers));
console.log('sum2', sum2(1, 2, 1, ...numbers));
```